# Not all elements will be marshalled by JAXB

Tags: jaxb, marshalling

Unfortunatelly after marshalling some elements are empty and want to be serialized.

Marshalling:

```
public static <T> String marschallObjectToXml(final Class<T> clazz, T object) {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, UTF_8);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        QName qName = new QName(clazz.getPackage().getName(), clazz.getSimpleName());
        Object objectToMarshal = new JAXBElement<T>(qName, clazz, object);

        // object to XML
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(objectToMarshal, sw);
        return sw.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(FEHLER_BEIM_PARSEN + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Object 1 :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"personen", "kinder"})
public static class PersonenUndBeziehungen {

    @XmlElement(name = "Personen", required = true)
    protected BqDatenTyp.PersonenUndBeziehungen.Personen personen;
// ...
```

Object 2:

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"person"})
    public static class Personen {

        @XmlElement(name = "Person", required = true)
        protected List<PersonTyp> person;

        public List<PersonTyp> getPerson() {
            if (person == null) {
                person = new ArrayList<PersonTyp>();
            }
            return this.person;
        }
     // ...
```

Object 3:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "personTyp", propOrder = {"lfdID", "kundennummern", "typ", "vertriebsmassnahmen", "liquiditaet",
    "risikobereitschaft", "kenntnisseUndErfahrungen", "bankmitarbeiter", "mitglied", "natuerlichePerson",
    "juristischePerson", "betreuung", "beziehungen", "vermoegenswerte"})
public class PersonTyp {

    @XmlElement(name = "LfdID", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NormalizedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "normalizedString")
    protected String lfdID;
    @XmlElement(name = "Kundennummern", required = true)
    protected PersonTyp.Kundennummern kundennummern;
    @XmlElement(name = "Typ", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "normalizedString")
    // ...
```

If I start the programm in debug mode, I can see, that the List: T Object --> PersonenUndBeziehungen -> Personen -> Person will be filled with one object and it's not empty. But after serialization I see:

```
        <personenUndBeziehungen>
            <kinder/>
            <personen/> <!-- THIS SHOULD NOT BE EMPTY. IS EMPTY??? -->
        </personenUndBeziehungen>
```

Any ideas!?
Thanks a lot in advance!
PS: Java 1.7